# Get rewrite slug of custom post type in template

Tags: custom-post-types, php, plugin-development, customization

How do I get the rewrite slug of a custom post type inside a template?

```
register_post_type( 'products',
    'rewrite'     => array( 'slug' => 'fabrications' ),
    // ... etc
);
```

Now inside my template file inside the `global $post` there is post_type property. But I can't find the `rewrite slug` anywhere.

Please help.

**Update:**
    I needed this for permalinks inside a template part where there are categories displayed.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_site_url() . '/' . $post_type_slug . '/category/' . $category->slug . '/' ?>" class="cat-bar__label"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
```

Comment: I've posted a solution, but can I ask why? It's unusual to need this inside a template.

Comment: Sure. See update.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the post type properties using [`get_post_type_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_object/). The rewrite argument will be a property if the returned object:

```
$post_type_object = get_post_type_object( 'products' );
$rewrite_slug     = $post_type_object->rewrite['slug'];
```

---

**Update**

> I needed this for permalinks inside a template part where there are categories displayed.

No you don't. To get the URL to a category archive, use [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/):

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $category ) ); ?>" class="cat-bar__label"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is much better indeed.

Comment: Thanks for this, was looking for the first part of your answer. Regarding the second part just a little note: you can pass the term_id to `get_term_link()`, but if you do have the whole term object, use it. do not only pass the ID, since `get_term_link()` needs the object. it can work with the ID as well, but will use it, to get the object. and if you only have the ID, make sure to pass a number, since a string is considered a slug <3